# Why is this regex over /var/lib/dpkg/status showing non-installed packages

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, apt

I have a script which is intended to list the largest installed packages on Ubuntu. I can't remember where I got it from and I don't understand it.

```
sed -ne '/^Package: \(.*\)/{s//\1/;h;};/^Installed-Size: \(.*\)/{s//\1/;G;s/\n/ /;p;}' /var/lib/dpkg/status | sort -n
```

It's reading `/var/lib/dpkg/status`

The bottom two lines of output on my system are

```
340296 cuda-visual-tools-7-5
432665 texlive-latex-extra-doc
```

If I try to `apt-get remove` these packages it says they're not installed.

Are they *actually* not installed, in which case the above script is wrong, or are they installed but not removable via these names, being some sort of pseudo-package or whatever?

Comment: What does the `Status:` line for those packages say?

Comment: `Status: deinstall ok config-files` I have done `apt-get autoclean` and `autoremove` exhaustively. If it's not installed why does it have an `Installed-Size`?